# programmatically change orientation from Landscape to Portrait Mode xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing an app with Xamarin MVVMCross technology and would like to ask a question about InterfaceOrientation option: all view controllers of application support all orientations but one should use only Portrait mode.
When I go to that ViewController from others in Portrait mode, I am able to keep my portrait viewcontroller in Portrait mode due to method in my AppDelegate.cs :

```
[Export("application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:")]
public UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, IntPtr forWindow)
{
    if (this.RestrictRotation)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}
```

But when I go to my portraitview controller when device in LandscapeLeft(LandscapeRight) orientations, GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations from AppDelegate.cs method is not called and that view controller is opened in Landscape mode.
Is there a way to programmatically change orientation from Landscape to Portrait Mode just for one view controller in Xamarin IOS?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your helper class;

```
public static void LockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask uIInterfaceOrientationMask, UIInterfaceOrientation uIInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate != null)
            {
                CommonUtils.LockOrientation(uIInterfaceOrientationMask);
                UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)uIInterfaceOrientation), new NSString("orientation"));
            }
        }
```

In AppDelegate.cs

```
    //Set the orientation for rest of the app
public UIInterfaceOrientationMask OrientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;

            public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application, UIWindow forWindow)
            {
                return OrientationLock;
            }
```

Now simply call the LockOrientation method wherever you would like to lock/change orientation.

Example:

```
CommonUtils.LockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait);
```

Comment: Thanks Singhal2, it is what i was looking for!

Comment: It saved my coding time.

Comment: Bug: UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey() for orientation should be passed a value from UIDeviceOrientation not UIInterfaceOrientation. Don't get them confused as LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight have different values.

Comment: Could you please provide some reference for your comment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the orientation of a single ViewController don't use the `AppDelegate` `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` method instead use the one in the ViewController you want to control.

These lines will prevent the ViewController you implement this method to get any other orientation but Portrait.

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}
```

**Note:** You will need to repeat the same for every ViewController in case you want to force the orientation to more than one.

Answer (score 0):

i hope that work.. 
put in your controller class

```
public override void DidRotate(UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        base.DidRotate(fromInterfaceOrientation);
        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView();
        alert.Title = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation + "";
        alert.AddButton("ok");
        alert.Show();

    }
```